# Laravel Socialite using for getting tokens only?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, laravel-socialite

My question is Laravel Socialite using for getting tokens only?

For example, I want make Facebook post thought API.
I cant find any methods in Socialite docs. Does it means, that Socialite using only for getting tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in https://socialiteproviders.com/, **thats only auth additions**.

As auth, it response basic user information, but if you need make full API list, you need find another solution.

I find solution, but I want explain my task:

**I need use Instagram API through Facebook.**

Facebook has PHP SDK for using Facebook API, with examples, which arent show any instagram cases with API using. I didnt manage Instagram API with Facebook SDK.
And I cant find any working solutions using Facebook SDK.

1. So, in my case, I am using Laravel [Socialite](https://socialiteproviders.com/InstagramBasic/) for generate redirect URL and access token.
2. And then I am using [manual HTTP  client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) for Instagram API with token from Socialite.